# Проблема с кодировкой при записи в файл Java

Tags: java, файлы, кодировка, запись

Код для добавления написанной строки после определенной строки.
Раньше проблема была и при чтении из файла, но поменяла в настройках кодировку на windows-1251, после чего буквы из файла idea начала понимать, а вот строку которую надо записать русскими буквами не понимает. Что делать? может есть какой то код который можно написать вначале программы, чтобы она меняла кодировку или еще что то в настройках? Подскажите пожалуйста.
[image: Изменение настроек на windows-1251]

[image: Результаты]

```
    package Main;

    import java.io.*;
...

    public class WorkWithFile {
        private String path;

        public WorkWithFile(String path) {
            this.path = path;

        }

        //возвращает массив номер строк сверху (первая строка - 1) str (после которых надо вставить)
        private ArrayList<Integer> countNumberPosStr(String str) throws IOException {
            File file = new File(path);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
.....
        }

        //создает список со всеми строками файла
        private LinkedList<String> writeArrayOfAllStrings() throws IOException {
.....
}

        //создается новый файл, с добавленными строками
        public void addStringInNewFile(String str, String str_add) throws IOException {

            File new_file = new File("D:/other/Text/File.txt");
            boolean create = new_file.createNewFile();
            boolean flag = false;
            if (create) {

                FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:/other/Text/File.txt");
                int count = 1;
                int count_array = 0;
                ArrayList<Integer> quantity_strings = this.countNumberPosStr(str);
                LinkedList<String> strings = this.writeArrayOfAllStrings();
                ListIterator<String> it = strings.listIterator();

                for (String p :
                        strings) {
                    file.write(it.next() + "\n");
                    if (count_array < quantity_strings.size()) {
                        if (count == quantity_strings.get(count_array)) {
                            file.write(str_add + "\n");
                            count_array++;
                            flag = true;
                        }
                    }
                    count++;
                }

                if (flag) {
                    file.flush();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("ошибка при создании файла");
            }
        }
    }
```

----и вот в главной программе при вызове не понимает строку вторую

```
public class ChangeText {
    private static WorkWithFile work;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        work = new WorkWithFile("D:/other/Text/for2.txt");
        work.addStringInNewFile("123 45", "это жея(");
    }
}
```

Comment: Не пробовали использовать PrintStream для записи в файл?

Comment: PrintStream тоже кракозябру записывает(

Answer (score 2):

Спустя три дня откопала решение:

```
  PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter("D:/other/Text/File.txt", "Cp1251");
...
  file.println(str_add);
```

Правда в настройках idea сделала обратно UTF-8, а не windows

Comment: Главное кодировку самого файла txt, с которым работаем, тоже сделать UTF-8